# Is it possible to configure ctrl-w (delete word)?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

Normally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes back to the last whitespace.

Is it possible to configure it to use additional characters, such as `/`?

Edit: To be more clear: I don't want to configure the key for it, I want to have the deletion stop on `/` as well.

Example:

```
vim /foo/bar^W
vim /foo/
```

Answer (score 43):

For this specific issue, you can also use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

```
$ cd /home/me/test/a_dir/    # Alt + Backspace
$ cd /home/me/test/          # Alt + Backspace
$ cd /home/me/               # ...
```

Good reference: [Adventures with bash's word erase](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/bash-word-erase.html)

Comment: Awesome!  Most other answers suggest rebinding `Ctrl+w` or Ctrl+b or something to `unix-filename-rubout`, but it's so much better that there's a built-in binding: M-backspace (Alt+backspace or Esc backspace)

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: @ethanjyx oh. I am working on GNU bash. Are you also in this flavour?

Answer (score 33):

What worked for me was to add the following lines to my .bashrc

```
stty werase undef
bind '\C-w:unix-filename-rubout'
```

You need the undef line otherwise bash ignores your new binding for `C-w`

Comment: It should be noted that `stty werase undef` will stop you from using C-w in any program (bind will allow you to use in readline)

Answer (score 27):

You should be able to use Esc, then backspace to delete words delimited by slashes.

You can change this by putting this in you .bashrc:

```
bind '\C-f:unix-filename-rubout'
```

Now use `Ctrl+f`  to do what you want.

Comment: thanks, that's the command that works. is there a way to overwrite the command of C-w? If I change it to `C-w:...`, the default behaviour of deleting to the next space still kicks in. On a different key (like F) if works fine.

Comment: I don't think ctrl-w is managed by the shell alone. It may be managed by the tty also. What are your tty setting shown by `stty -a`? do you have control-w as default char for werase? If you remove that setting from tty, with comman `stty werase undef`, does then bash works as expected?

Answer (score 8):

With bash you can get the desired effect, putting the following in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
bind '"\C-w":backward-kill-word'
```

Hit `CTRL+V` and the your key combination to see what it looks like for your terminal emulator. For instance `CTRL+bksp` can be interpreted different on different terminals e.g. `^H` or `^?`. The `^` character is the same as `CTRL`.

Comment: I think I wasn't specific enough with my question. I wanted to have `/` as an additional stop-character, not a way to bind the delete-word-command on an other key. I edited my question

Comment: Using backward-kill-word binded to \C-w, it will erase backwards to the last given forward slash if present in a word and it will erase words delimited by whitespace. This is not what you wanted?

Comment: My system uses `^F` - but using `"\^F"` in the script above doesn't work

Comment: The `Ctrl` character is written `\C` in the script and not `\^`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is specific to Mac OS, but I couldn't do a thing with C-w without also setting this readline option:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars Off
```

I added that to my ~/.inputrc, along with:

```
C-w: backward-kill-word
```

Now I'm able to delete backwards one word at a time.

Source: https://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/bash-word-erase.html