# How to configure Ctrl+w as delete word in zsh

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

I want to delete a word by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in `zsh` like.

```
vim /foo/bar^W
vim /foo/
```

And found a solution for `bash`, but `bind` is not in zsh function.

[Is it possible to configure ctrl-w (delete word)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/is-it-possible-to-configure-ctrl-w-delete-word)

How can I configure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as a `delete-word`?

Comment: See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets-1 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=select-word-style and

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a snippet from *.zshrc* i've been using:

```
my-backward-delete-word() {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\//}
    zle backward-delete-word
}
zle -N my-backward-delete-word
bindkey '^W' my-backward-delete-word
```

I recall this was the original source:
http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2001/msg00870.html

Comment: The default `emacs` key binding table in ZLE binds ^W to `backward-kill-word` rather than to `backward-delete-word`, note.

Answer (score 16):

Just for your information, I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200998/1067688) to be far more elegant. I quote:

> Another option is to set `WORDCHARS` (non-alphanumeric chars treated as part of a word) to something that doesn't include `/`.
>
> You can also tweak this if you'd prefer `^w` to break on dot, underscore, etc.  In `~/.zshrc` I have:
>
> ```
> WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'
> ```

## UPDATE (2/Mar/2020)

As @Patryk pointed out on the comments below, this doesn't work for `ZSH >= 5.7`. Here is an update that I tested and work on `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)`.

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash

export WORDCHARS='.-'
```

Comment: This makes `M-d` less useful.

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers so far provide all the properties that bash has. Namely:

- CTRL-w deletes any non-space char.
- CTRL-w puts the text in the kill ring (so it can then be pasted with CTRL-y).
- CTRL-w *appends* the text to the kill ring upon subsequent kill commands (CTRL-w, alt-backspace, alt-d, etc).

Moreover, we don't want to set WORDCHARS globally as it affects other functions.

Here is a solution that satisfies all the above:

```
        # Ctrl-w - delete a full WORD (including colon, dot, comma, quotes...)
        my-backward-kill-word () {
            # Add colon, comma, single/double quotes to word chars
            local WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>:,"'"'"
            zle -f kill # Append to the kill ring on subsequent kills.
            zle backward-kill-word
        }
        zle -N my-backward-kill-word
        bindkey '^w' my-backward-kill-word
```