# How can I delete whole word when using oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I use standard zsh <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> deletes whole word (i.e. it would remove whole `foo-bar`). However, when using `oh-my-zsh` I would delete only last part of the word and leave `foo-`. I want to be able to use both.

I want to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to delete whole word. I've tried to define my own function with `WORDCHARS` overridden but with no luck:

```
myf () {
  local WORDCHARS=''
  zle backward-kill-word
}
zle -N myf
bindkey '^Q' myf
```

There are couple of similar questions but this one is when using zsh **with** oh-my-zsh.

Comment: A related answer is of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250700/5132 .

Comment: I just tried a clean install with oh-my-zsh and your code above and it works fine for me. Are you sure you don't have something else sourced that is messing things up?