# Readline: treat dash as a word break character

Tags: bash, readline

I'd like Readline to consider words separated by dashes as single words, just as Vim does by default.

So for example, if I'm at the end of the line below and I type `ctrl-W`

```
cp long-filename-with-dashes
```

Readline would delete only `dashes` instead of the whole string until the space.

Is there any way to configure this without breaking other things?

Comment: possibly a duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/is-it-possible-to-configure-ctrl-w-delete-word

Comment: @val0x00ff That question is about using `/` as word separator, not exactly the same. I was able to find the right setting in there anyway, so thanks for pointing me there!

Comment: oops, I read the question wrongly.. probably use `Esc+Backspace` or `Alt+Backspace` which is mapped to `backward-kill-word`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired behavior with this two lines in my `bashrc`:

```
stty werase undef
bind '\C-w: backward-kill-word'
```

Still no idea about possible side-effects though.

**Edit**: I found the proper way to set this in the `inputrc` without touching the `bashrc` and resorting to `stty` thanks to [this article](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/bash-word-erase.html):

```
set bind-tty-special-chars Off

$if Bash
  \C-w: backward-kill-word
$endif
```

**Update:** Looks like `bind-tty-special-chars` breaks the behavior of `w`, `e` and `<c-w>` in Vim (probably among other things), so the best solution for me is to set `stty werase undef` in the `bashrc` and `\C-w: backward-kill-word` in the `inputrc`.

Comment: This wasn't working for me – I needed to  use a capital W in the binding (i.e. `"\C-W": backward-kill-word`).